# trying to install magento 2.3 on mamp pro and getting session has expired

Tags: php, magento, mamp

I am trying to install magento version 2.3.5 p1 on mamp pro server on mac os 10.15.7 Catalina. I have a following base url for it:

```
http://magmono:8888/
```

I somehow managed to install it but getting pretty typical error. When I try to add somethin to cart I get your session has expired error. The solution to update base urls to 127.0.0.1 doesn't help at all there is no such url. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well finaly I overcame the problem. Just went to admin pannel then store configuration and default cookie configuration. There I have set use http only to validate cookie to no. I do understand that it will compromise user security but I think it is fare to say that it is ok for local development with only one client visiting the site